# How can I use Clebsch-Gordan coefficients to decompose this group representation?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a compact group, $\alpha$ be a unitary irrep of $G$ with carrier space $\mathcal A$, and $\beta$ be a unitary irrep of $G$ with carrier space $\mathcal B$. Then, the action of $G$ on vectors in $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B$ is found by tensoring $\alpha$ with $\beta$, so that

$$(\mathbf{a}\otimes \mathbf{b})\mapsto\alpha_g\otimes\beta_g (\mathbf{a}\otimes \mathbf{b})=(\alpha_g\mathbf{a})\otimes(\beta_g\mathbf{b}),$$

for every $g\in G$, and one can use Clebsch-Gordan coefficients to decompose this tensor representation. What I have, instead, is a representation of $G$ on linear maps $M:\mathcal B\rightarrow\mathcal A$:
$$M\mapsto\alpha_g\,M\,\beta_g^\dagger.$$

How can I decompose this representation? I have thought that it might be related to the decomposition of a representation of $G$ acting on $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B^*$, so that the action of $G$ can be written as

$$\alpha_g\otimes \beta_g^\dagger(\mathbf{a}_i\otimes\mathbf{b}^\dagger_j)=(\alpha_g\mathbf{a}_i)\otimes (\mathbf{b}^\dagger_j\beta_g^\dagger).$$

I am trying to understand if I can use the standard Clebsch-Gordan coefficients to decompose $\alpha_g\otimes \beta_g^\dagger$ (because $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B^*$ are canonically isomorphic, so the solution could be as simple as suitably modifying the C-G coefficients, perhaps with a complex conjugate in the right place, or a transposition). But then I'm thrown off by the fact that I don't really have things like $\alpha_g\otimes \beta_g^\dagger$, but rather things like $\alpha_g\,(\#)\,\beta_g^\dagger$, where $\#$ is a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Your representation is just the representation of $G$ on $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}^{*}$, as you noticed. But as $G$-representations, $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}^{*}$ are isomorphic by the map
$$b \mapsto (b, - )$$
which is $G$-invariant because, for any $g \in G, b, b'\in \mathcal{B}$,
$$g\cdot b (b') \mapsto (g\cdot b, b') = (b, g^{-1} \cdot b) = (g\cdot (b, -)) (b').$$

I think you actually noted the above. So, if $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}^{*}$ are isomorphic as $G$-representations,

$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(B, A) \cong \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}^{*} \cong \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$$
so the decomposition into irreducibles should be the same.

Comment: Perfect! So I can use C-G as it is to decompose my representation of $G$ on $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(B,A)$ as if it were a representation of $G$ on $A\otimes B$. But when I have performed the decomposition I end up with the direct sum of irreps on subspaces of $A\otimes B$, how does this translate back to a direct sum of irreps on subspaces of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(B,A)$?

Comment: The direct sum of irreps that makes up $A \otimes B$ is exactly the same as the direct sum of irreps that makes up $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(B, A).$ Anymore info would require more information about $A$ and $B$ (for example, if you want to actually write the irreps in terms of $A$ and $B$)

Comment: Wait, why are you saying that the irreps "make up" $\mathcal A\otimes \mathcal B$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(B,A)$? I thought that the irreps were things "acting on" those spaces

Comment: The term irreps of a group $G$ refers to the irreducible representations of the group. When I say the irreps that make up $A \otimes B$, I am referring to the irreducible subrepresentations of $A \otimes B$, which make up $A \otimes B$ in the sense that $A \otimes B$ is the direct sum of its irreducible subrepresentations.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "In the mathematical field of representation theory, group representations describe abstract groups in terms of linear transformations of vector spaces"
From the encyclopedia of mathematics: "[Representation of a Group] A homomorphism of the group into the group of all invertible transformations of a set $V$."

Representations are things that act on vector spaces, no?

Comment: A representation refers to a linear action of a group on a vector space. It is thus a way in which a group acts on a particular vector space. This is equivalent to a homomorphism from the group to the group of invertible linear transformations of the vector space $V$ (as wiki says). However, people usually denote by a representation $V$ both the vector space and the action of $G$ on $V$.